# Выводить в phpstorm annotate не commit, a comment

Tags: phpstorm, mercurial

Как в phpstorm настроить вывод в annotate comment? В интерфейсе можно вывести ревизию, автора, дату, и commit номер, а сам комент не могу найти как вывести. Конечно при наведении внизу пишется комент, или через mercurial history можно увидеть, но конкретно в этот столбец как добавить? Может кто сталкивался и знает как сделать? Может плагин кто написал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По информации на сайте JetBrains, на полях должно отображаться только имя автора + минимум информации. Более подробную информацию можно найти на [странице официальной документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate_blame).

Comment: @7-zete-7, а вроде удобная штука, почему не реализовали

Comment: Можете оставить предложение о добавлении этой функции на [их YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)